# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arctan\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{0.25}}\right)$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\arctan\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{0.25}}\right)$$ is convergent.

I'm stuck not sure what test I should use, because almost all tests require $a_n$ to be always positive which is not the case here. Do I have to test for absolute convergence instead?

Comment: *Hint.* You should be able to use the alternating series test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\arctan\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{0.25}}\right)=(-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac1{(n+1)^{0.25}}\right)$. On the other hand, $\left(\arctan\left(\frac1{(n+1)^{0.25}}\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence, which converges to $0$. Therefore, you can apply Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Wow nice catch. I did not think to use that arctan is an odd function. Thank you.

Comment: @user474242 I'm glad that you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pedestrian way (see the other answer for a better approach)

$$\arctan\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{1/4}}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}-\frac{(-1)^{3n}}{3n^{3/4}}+O(\frac{1}{n^{5/4}})$$

$\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}$ converges by the alternating series test, $\sum_n\frac{(-1)^{3n}}{n^{3/4}}$ converges by Dirichlet test, and $\sum_n O(\frac{1}{n^{5/4}})$ converges by the comparison test.